# Can Mapbox expressions be used with `opacity-transition` properties?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to use expressions to fade in elements on a map, for example:

```
'fill-opacity-transition': {
    duration: 1000,
    delay: [
        'match', ['get', 'year'],
            '2000', 1000,
            '2001', 2000,
            '2002', 3000,
            4000
    ],
},
```

The above does not work, even though it works for properties like `fill-color`.

I also tried moving the entire `{ duration:... delay:...}` object inside of the values that the expression returns, but that didn't work either.

Is it possible to use expressions with `opacity-transition` properties? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve **isn't possible** currently. These transition properties are "just" plain numbers. No expressions.

From the official docs ([Mapbox GL js documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/style-spec/reference/transition/)):

- **delay**

  Optional **number** greater than or equal to 0. Units in milliseconds.

  Defaults to 0.

  Length of time before a transition begins.
- **duration**

  Optional **number** greater than or equal to 0. Units in milliseconds.

  Defaults to 300.

  Time allotted for transitions to complete.